# Groovy closures with automatic currying

Tags: groovy, currying

I'm just getting started with Groovy, coming from a background of Haskell, C++ and a bit of Java.

Lets say I write a closure like the following:

```
def mult = { x, y -> x * y }
```

Later on I can then write `mult(3,5)`.

But if I write `mult(3)`, I get a compile error.

I could of course write `mult.curry(3)`, but that seems a bit ugly to me.

So then I could try this approach:

```
def mult = { x -> { y -> x * y }}
```

Now, `mult(3)` works fine, but to multiply two numbers, I have to write `mult(3)(5)` to multiply two numbers.

What I want is the best of both worlds. I want to be able to write `mult(3)`, `mult(3,5)` and `mult(3)(5)`. Anyway to get closures to behave like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make something like this to "currify" your closure:

```
def currify(fn) {
    { Object... args ->
        if (args.size() == fn.maximumNumberOfParameters) {
            fn(*args)
        } else {
            currify(fn.curry(*args))
        }
    }
}

def mult = currify { x, y -> x * y }
def twice = mult(2)

assert mult(2, 5) == 10
assert twice(5) == 10
assert mult(2)(5) == 10
```