# Groovy error when currying

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, iterator, closures

The code which gives the error is on [ideone here](http://ideone.com/kVulMg), sorry I haven't been able to give a more minimal example.

Because it's a bit long, I'll explain it.

The `Unfoldr` class, and `unfoldr` function basically to what [`unfoldr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#g:9) does in Haskell, creates lists. But in this case I create an iterator.

The `map` function is again, much like [`map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#g:2) in Haskell. It gets passed an iterator, calls `unfoldr` with the iterator as the "state" and creates a new iterator which gives the same results as the old iterator but with the given function applied to them.

`splitlist` breaks a list into lists `n` long, i.e. splitlist(2)([1,2,3,4]) results in an iterator that first gives [1,2] then [3,4].

`currify` takes a function and allows one to partially apply it. For example,

```
f = currify { a, b -> a + b }
```

Means f(2,3) = 5, f(2)(3) = 5, and f(2) is a closure that adds 2. I got this from and answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514659/groovy-closures-with-automatic-currying).

Currifying a one argument closure should really do nothing to it and act like the identify function on it.

Finally, I've overridden the `>>` operator on iterators so I can use it basically like a pipe.

My question is why line `F:` fails, but lines `A-E` all succeed?

The code (which is long) is here, and like I said, also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/kVulMg).

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked

class Unfoldr<A,B> implements java.util.Iterator<A>
{
  public Unfoldr(Closure<Object[]> f, B init) 
  {
    this.f = f;
    this.state = f(init);
  }

  public synchronized A next() throws java.util.NoSuchElementException
  {
    if (hasNext())
    {
      A curr = state[0];
      state = f(state[1]);
      return curr;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
    }
  }

  public synchronized boolean hasNext() 
  {
    return state != null;
  }

  public void remove() { throw UnsupportedOperationException; }

  private Closure<Object[]> f;

  private Object[] state;
}

def currify(fn) {
    { Object... args ->
        if (args.size() == fn.maximumNumberOfParameters) {
            fn(*args)
        } else {
            currify(fn.curry(*args))
        }
    }
};

def unfoldr = currify { f, init -> new Unfoldr(f, init) };

def map = currify { f, l -> unfoldr({ l2 -> if (l2.hasNext()) { def e = l2.next(); return [f(e), l2]} else { return null; } } , l.iterator())}

def splitlist = currify {
n, l ->
  unfoldr(
    { 
      l2 -> 
        try 
        { 
          def a = new Object[n];
          for (i in 0..(n-1))
          {
            a[i] = l2.next();
          }
          return [a, l2]; 
        } 
        catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) 
        {
          return null;
        }
    }, 
    l
  )
};

Iterator.metaClass.rightShift = { PrintStream os -> delegate.each({ x -> os.println(x) }) }
Iterator.metaClass.rightShift = { Closure f -> f(delegate) }

id = { x -> x }
f = currify { x -> x }

println "A: "
[[1,2],[3,4]].iterator() >> System.out
println "B: "
[1,2,3,4].iterator() >> splitlist(2) >> System.out
println "C: "
[[1,2],[3,4]].iterator() >> map(id) >> System.out
println "D: "
[1,2,3,4].iterator() >> splitlist(2) >> map(id) >> System.out
println "E: "
[[1,2],[3,4]].iterator() >> map(f) >> System.out
println "F: "
[1,2,3,4].iterator() >> splitlist(2) >> map(f) >> System.out
```

Output:

```
A: 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
B: 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
C: 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
D: 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
E: 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
F: 
Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't curry 2 arguments for a closure with 1 parameters.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't curry 2 arguments for a closure with 1 parameters.
    at prog$_currify_closure8.doCall(prog.groovy:42)
    at prog$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(prog.groovy:49)
    at Unfoldr.<init>(prog.groovy:8)
    at prog$_run_closure1.doCall(prog.groovy:47)
    at prog$_currify_closure8.doCall(prog.groovy:40)
    at prog$_run_closure2.doCall(prog.groovy:49)
    at prog$_currify_closure8.doCall(prog.groovy:40)
    at prog$_run_closure5.doCall(prog.groovy:75)
    at prog.run(prog.groovy:91)
```

Comment: I've opened another question which I believe has isolated the problem, the link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890893/groovy-same-parameters-different-results

I'll award this bounty to an answer there, just make a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like line F fails cause

```
def e = l2.next()
```

returns Object[] instead of ArrayList