# Groovy: same parameters, different results

Tags: groovy

In the below code, `x.test()` returns `[1,2]`.

So `y = [1,2]`.

Yet `f([1,2])` prints `1`, but `f(y)` prints `2`.

How do I write `f(y)` so it prints `1`?

Perversely, `f(z)` prints `1`, even though `z = y`.

```
def f = { Object... args -> println args.size(); };

class Test { Object[] test() { return [1,2]; } }

def x = new Test();
def y = x.test();
def z = [1,2];

f([1,2]); // 1
f(y); // 2
f(z); // 1
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `y` and `z`, while they appear to be the same, are actually of different types. `y` is an `Object[]` while `z` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Groovy handles arrays and lists differently, automatically coercing the former into a varargs parameter list, but not the latter.

```
println y.getClass(); // class [Ljava.lang.Object
println z.getClass(); // class java.util.ArrayList
```

As for a solution to your problem, either change your `test()` to return a `List` instead of an array:

```
class Test { List test() { return [1,2]; } }
```

or manually coerce the array into a list when you pass it to `f`:

```
f(y as List); // 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression `[1,2]` in Groovy denotes an ArrayList with two members, `Integer.valueOf(1)` and `Integer.valueOf(2)`. Thus when you call `f([1,2])` Groovy creates a single-element array containing this ArrayList as its only item, and passes that array as the closure argument.

But `x.test()` is declared to return `Object[]` so the `[1,2]` ArrayList will be converted to a two element `Object[]` by the `return`. Thus `y` is already an `Object[]` and does not need to be boxed up in a varargs array to be passed to `f`.

You need to turn `y` back into a list, either by changing the return type of `test()` or by saying

```
f(y as List)
```

Conversely, you can use the *spread* operator

```
f(*z) // 2
```

which will extract the elements of the ArrayList and pass them as individual arguments to the call (which will then be packaged up into a varargs array as usual).

Answer (score 0):

`y` is an instance of `[Ljava.lang.Object` whereas `[1,2]` and `z` are of instance of `ArrayList`

The Array has the `size() == 2` and the `ArrayList`s count as one argument, but they contain two elements

Groovy does some type converting for you ;)